If $f'(x) = O(1)$, then $f(x) = O(x)$
CONTEXT
While self-studying Real Analysis I came across the following assertion, and tried to prove it.
PROBLEM

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function, defined in some right (left) neighborhood of $a$ (which can also be infinite). If $f'(x) = O(1)$ for $x\to a^+$ ($a^-$) then $f(x) = O(x)$ for $x\to a^+$ ($a^-$).

MY TENTATIVE PROOF
My proof makes use of a generalization of L'Hopital's Rule: if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions on a right neighborhood of $a$, $g'(x)\neq 0$ near $a$, and either $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a^+}g(x) = 0$, or $\lim_{x\to a^+}|g(x)| = +\infty$, then
$$\liminf_{x\to a^+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} \leq \liminf_{x\to a^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\leq \limsup_{x\to a+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\leq \limsup_{x\to a^+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.\tag{1}\label{dlh}$$
Let us consider first the case $a = +\infty$ (or $-\infty$). Using $g(x) = x$ in \eqref{dlh}, and the hypothesis $f'(x) = O(1)$ for $x\to +\infty$ leads to
$$\limsup_{x\to +\infty}\frac{f(x)}x \leq \limsup_{x\to +\infty} f'(x) <+\infty,$$
which immediately yields $f(x) = O(x)$.
Suppose now $a$ is finite. Then we must have
$$-\infty < \liminf_{x\to a^+}f(x) = \limsup_{x\to a^+}f(x) < +\infty.$$
If $\limsup f(x) \neq \liminf f(x)$, in fact, by the Mean Value Theorem the derivative would necessarily be unbounded. The same conclusion is reached if $f(x)$ diverges when $x$ approaches $a$. Define therefore
$$L \equiv \lim_{x\to a^+} f(x),$$
and
$$f_1(x) = f(x)-L.$$
Now we can apply \eqref{dlh} to $f_1(x)$ and $g(x) = x-a$, and reach again the conclusion that
$$\limsup_{x\to a^+} \frac{f_1(x)}{x-a}\leq \limsup_{x\to a^+} f_1'(x) = \limsup_{x\to a^+}f'(x) < +\infty,$$
implying that $f_1(x) = O(x)$, and therefore $f(x) = O(x)$, as desired.
QUESTIONS
Is the assertion correct? Is my proof correct? If the assertion is correct, can you suggest some alternative approaches to its proof? If it is not, can you provide me with (a hint to) a counterexample?

Do you really mean $O(x)$ or should it be $O(x-a)$ (in the case of finite nonzero $a$)?

It's likely that the proof correctly shows that $$f_1(x)$$ is $$O(x-a)$$, but that doesn't imply that $$f(x)$$ itself is $$O(x-a)$$.

@GregMartin Thanks for pointing that out. For the finite case we can only state that $f(x)-L = O(x-a)$, correct?

Just use the mean value theorem

"$f(x) = O(g(x))$ as $x \to a$" means that there is some neighborhood of $a$ and some $M > 0$ such that $|f(x)| < M|g(x)|$ in that neighborhood (different types of limits just mean different concepts of "neighborhood"). $f(x) = x + C$ has derivative $f'(x) = 1$, which is certainly $O(1)$ everywhere, but $f(x)$ is not $O(x)$ at $a = 0$ unless $C = 0$. Note that if $|g|$ is bounded away from both $\infty$ and $0$ in a neighborhood of $a$, then $O(g(x))$ is the same as $O(1)$ at $a$. So $f$ being differentiable is enough to show $f(x) = O(x)$ at finite $a \ne 0$.
